# VS 2008 The debugging tool doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have problem with Visual Studio Team System 2008.

The compiler suddenly stopped watching for my breatpoints, no matter where I place them. I compile my project by F5 button. How to turn it on again ?

Comment: Have you switched to a release build by accident?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what You mean ;)

Comment: What kind of solution are you developing? ASP.NET, Console Application, Windows Forms?

Comment: Build > Configuration Manager > Active solution configuration or the drop down on the Standard Toolbar next to the "Start Debugging" icon

Comment: everything is set to Debug and all checkboxes are checked

Comment: Ah well - I was only trying to eliminate the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, clear all the breakpoints. After that clean the solution. Then rebuild the solution. Now set the breakpoints again.

Sometimes I also delete the bin and debug folders (manually). If that doesn't work, close Visual Studio and open it again.

If you're using the bundled web server that comes with Visual Studio called Cassini (the icon that stays close to your computer clock), shut it down. Even when you stop the application the standard ASP.NET development web server stays alive. Kill it too.

If the above doesn't help, check the following links:

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/21865-Visual-Studio-NET-Debugger-Does-Not-Stop.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/372106.aspx

Comment: I also closed the web server without success

Comment: folder cleaning didn't help, the compiler restart too

Comment: Nope, none of the options mentioned in this links didn't help

Comment: I'm running out of options... :) The ultimate solution: restart your computer... :o)

Comment: OK, I solved it - the reason was, in the project Properties->Web tab was selected option "Use Visual Studio Development Server". When I selected the option "Use Local IIS Web Server" the debug tool magically came back. Thanks for help :)